# How to interpret a specific mathematical notation in "FIPS 202" (SHA-3 / Keccak)

Tags: implementation, sha-3, keccak, notation

tl;dr  **What does "d <= |Z|" mean in the context of bit array manipulations?**

As a learning exercise I'm working on an implementation of SHA-3.  I am not a cryptography specialist in any way but I have implemented similar algorithms in the past such as MD5 and SHA1, so I am roughly conversant with the kinds of operations that happen in such algorithms.

I have been working through the document "FIPS PUB 202" (freely available as a PDF here: http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.202).

I am finding this a hard document to understand but I'm getting near to completing the program and I'm unsure about the meaning of the following line of text in section 4, algorithm 8 (page 19)  the SPONGE function...

[image]
**My problem is with step 9**.  I do not understand what "|Z|" means in this context.

This algorithm deals with truncating and concatenating an array Z of bits (which could be several hundred bits long) until this condition is met at which point the first "d" bits of Z is returned to the calling function.

- My first thought was that |Z| means "the length of Z in bits", but that would be inconsistent -- they are using "len(...)" for that purpose in steps 1 and 2 (and elsewhere in the document).  This is the only place in the document where this "|...|" notation is used.
- I don't think it would mean "Abs(Z)" in the mathematical sense of converting Z to a positive value because the resulting number would be *extremely* large in almost all cases.  Converting Z (effectively a list of random bits) into an integer seems pointless and arbitrary.
- The "|...|" syntax is not mentioned in the glossary section. ("a || b" is mentioned but that's for array concatenation, which this is definitely not).
- I was also a bit puzzled by the use of "<=" in this condition.  Why bother to truncate if the length is equal, just return it as it is?  Further suggestion that it doesn't mean "length of Z".

So, how should I understand this slightly weird bit of text?  I doubt it's a mistake in the document because it's such an important algorithm and will have been stringently vetted by thousands of people much smarter than me.

Comment: I think it *does* mean the string length. It’s a common notation for it. If we’d have $=$ the Trunc function does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the length of $Z$ in bits; in other words, squeeze out consecutive $r$-bit blocks from the sponge until you have a $d$-bit string, truncating the last block if necessary.

I expect you may overestimate the number of people who proofread this document with an eye for details like that.  Most cryptographers studying it will have read the [Keccak reference](https://keccak.team/files/Keccak-reference-3.0.pdf#page=9), which uses slightly different notation meaning the same thing; most implementors will likely correctly guess that $|Z|$ and $\operatorname{len}(Z)$ mean the same thing when $Z$ is a bit string, or compare to another reference to confirm.

Comment: I see, thank you.  I'm glad I don't have to do this kind of implementation for a living.  It would be interesting to know how much scrutiny such a document undergoes before it's publication.  I only spotted this because my program doesn't work properly and I'm trying to iron out the bugs :)  Cheers.

Comment: What I hear on the grapevine is that the technology NIST uses for collaborative editing of their standards is emailing Word documents around.  I would love to hear a less miserable story than that, but I haven't yet.  The only other story I vaguely recall hearing—but I can't dig up a reference now, so it may have been apocryphal and/or a joke and/or something I hallucinated on my own—is that they have a LaTeX template to imitate the bad typographical style of those Word documents.

Comment: That is quite depressing, although I like the idea of LaTeX as a tool for creating documents with clarity and conciseness, it is rather esoteric and probably not in the metier of your average civil servant.  I won't bother submitting a document change request because my days of shouting into hurricanes are behind me :)